# IFrame frameborder 0, snapping to content only on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

So when I add no frameborder 0 on this external source iframe, it is ONLY snapping correctly on Chrome. Edge, FF, and IE it looks like crap. I cant effect the css either. Any idea what I could do here?

Correct look on Chrome.
[image: How it looks on chrome]

How it looks on every other browser.
[image]

Here is the iFrame

```
<iframe name="iframe" id="iframe" src="https://www.disprism.com/webar/login/" style="overflow:hidden;" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: decrease `height="200"` to whatever

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want here, can you be more precise? Your problem is the grey block on I.E right?

If my assumption is correct, then you should use "css borders" instead. Frameborder is not supported in HTML5.

Maybe try something like this https://codepen.io/Tryanium/pen/VRQjWK

```
#iframe{border: 0px;}
```

Source : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_frameborder.asp

**EDIT :**

I try on my computer on I.E[image]

As you can see I don't have any grey block, can you show us the rest of your CSS?

Comment: I the example you posted, the grey block is still above the form.